[Dataset Discovery::Table Search]Can HNSW and other indexes be applied to Table Search
I have previously learned about many efficient indexing structures in the field of vector retrieval, such as HNSW, DiskANN, LSH, etc. These indexes can help us solve ANN (Approximate Nearest Search) problems faster.
Recently, I have been researching the direction of Table Search Table Discovery in Data Lakes: State of the art and Future Directions,and have read the following literature.

A Sketch-based Index for Correlated Dataset Search
Efficiently Estimating Mutual Information Between Attributes Across Tables
Dataset Discovery in Data Lakes

Unfortunately, they have not made the source code public and focus on measuring the similarity between data tables.
Although I found the paper 'A study on efficient indexing for table search in data lakes' published at the International Conference on Semantic Computing (ICSC), I still do not know if an efficient indexing structure has been used in the field of table search.
Is the index used for vectors, such as HNSW, also applicable to data tables
I hope researchers in related fields can provide answers. Thank you very much

Have you tried the redis implementation?
